# Using where clause in SSRS expression

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, plot, where-clause

I have a data set with multiple rows. The columns are `name` and `plot`; `plot` is a binary image file. If I want to display the plot whose `name` is `secondPlot`, for example, how would I do this? I can display just the first plot with `=First(Fields!plot.Value, "DataSet1")` but haven't had any luck with retrieving a `plot` with a certain `name` value.

I found if `IIf` function but am unsure on its usage or whether it's actually what I'm looking for anyway. `=First(IIF(Fields!name.Value = "secondPlot", Fields.plot.Value, Nothing))` gives the error "The definition of the report '/MainReport' is invalid", for example.

For clarification, I'm typing this in Insert>Image>Database source.

Comment: Are you giving the user the option to select which plot is currently being shown? Or are you attempting to retrieve all plot images in one dataset and display at the same time?

Comment: @Aidan Neither really. I just want to display a single plot with a name that I specify, as opposed a single plot that just happens to be the first one in the database.

Comment: You should use a report parameter and use that parameter in the underlying query.

Comment: From your original question, I think you just needed to add your dataset - `=First(IIF(Fields!name.Value = "secondPlot", Fields.plot.Value, Nothing), "DataSet1"))` But I don't know if it will work with the Image like you want.

Answer (score 0):

Add a tablix component to your report, then assign your dataset to your tablix in the DataSetName property.

Delete columns and rows leaving only a textbox. Right click in the tablix and select `Tablix properties...` go to filter tab and add a new filter.

[image]

For Expression select `Name`, operator `=` and value use `="secondPlot"`.

The tablix will filter the row that contain `secondPlot` name and you can show the image in the tablix textbox by configuring background image property in the Fill tab.

Right click the textbox and select `Textbox properties` / Fill tab, in background image pane use settings like this.

[image]

**UPDATE:**

If your image is PNG, BMP, JPEG, GIF or X-PNG you can select the proper MIME Type.

Also if your image is encoded in Base64 you can try:

```
=System.Convert.FromBase64String(Fields!Plot.Value)
```

In the `Use this field:` expression.

Don't use any expression for the textbox. Just use the image field as  textbox background.

Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This seems very promising, I got up to the last instruction without a hitch! Could you please clarify what you mean by "you can show the image in the tablix textbox"? If I right click on the textbox and select Expression then I've tried typing in `=Fields!plot.Value`, but when it renders it the textbox is just blank. The same happens if I set it to `=Fields!name.Value` so it's not just an issue with the plot itself. Is this not where I should be setting it? (Update: I've also tried setting it by selecting Textbox properties after rightclicking, also to no avail).

Comment: Thanks, it's still not working correctly though unfortunately. I'm just seeing an empty textbox as if I hadn't done anything to it...